# Redirect visitor from one domain to another but keep the requested domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, multilingual

So I have a client who wants to have a multilingual web site that can be accessed by 2 domain names:

**domain_name_1.ru**

**domain_name_2.ee** (default)

The client doesn't want to log in and out every time he/she needs to create content for both sites.
The site itself is running on WordPress and right now the russian version of the site can be viewed by typing in:

**domain_name_2.ee/ru**

NB! the domain names are hosted at 2 different web hosts.

**domain_name_1.ru** web hosts only options are 1) to redirect the domain 2) to change name servers

---

Because of this, I'd like to know if it is possible to run both sites on 1 WordPress install and by using **.htaccess** can the domain name **domain_name_2.ee/ru** be masked to **domain_name_1.ru** when the user visits the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to redirect and keep **domain_name_1.ru** in the the address-bar by going to the host and creating an **alias** for it. Here is a list of my steps:

- created an **alias** for **domain_name_1.ru**
- created a **sub domain** of **ru.domain_name_2.ee**
- installed **WP** at **htdocs** directory
- enabled **MultiSite**
- created the **MS network**
- made the necessary MS changes to **wp-config** and **.htaccess** files in the htdocs directory
- made changes to the **name servers** by creating a **wildcard (*) A/AAA record** with redirect to the **IP address**
- created a new site with a domain name of **domain_name_1.ru** in WP MS.

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to do this is setup the `domain_name_1.ru` domain to use the `domain_name_2.ee/ru` directory as its document root (can do this using virtual host and the `DocumentRoot` directive). Otherwise you'll have to use mod_proxy, and ensure that it's loaded, and reverse proxy the request to the other domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain_name_1\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain_name_2.ee/ru/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Odd, I'm getting: `ERROR: Proxy can't be used in flags parameter of RewriteRule` in apache error_log. Could this be because of an alias I've created for `domain_name_1.ru`?

Comment: Removing the `[P]` proxy parameter solved the ERROR issue but now the **domain_name_1.ru** gets changed in the address-bar too.